# Mongoose Schema statics vs methods

Tags: mongoose-schema

In a mongoose schema we can create the method as two way **SchemaName.methods.fuctionName** and **SchemaName.statics.functionName**. 
Statics is more easier to use I just need to call **ModelName.Fuction**. Methods need to create object to use. My question is what different between them. What is the advantage and disadvantage of **statics** and **methods**. When I should use **statics** and when I should use **methods**.

```
// Users.js
UserSchema.statics.findUserStatics = async function(mail) {
    var findUser = await User.findOne({ mail: mail })
    return findUser
}

UserSchema.methods.findUserMethods = async function(mail) {
    var findUser = await User.findOne({ mail: mail })
    return findUser
}

// router.js

const { User } = require('./../models/Users')
router.post('/findbyStatics', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        var result = await User.findUserbyStatics(req.body.mail);
        res.status(200).send(result)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e.message)
    }
})

router.post('/findbyMethods', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        var user = new User()
        var result = await user.findUserbyMethods(req.body.mail);
        res.status(200).send(result)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e.message)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 6):

The **statics** object contains functions that are associated with the model itself, and not the individual instances. An advantage of using **statics** is that we do not need access to an instance of the class in order to access the functionality associated with it. For example: in your code snippet above, you attempt to search for a user. You correctly implemented a **static** member. If you had used a **method**, you would have been required to instantiate a user object to search for a user. 
Use **methods** when you will have objects already instantiated, and use **statics** when you will not.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to think about this is to think about `this`!

In a `statics` method the `this` refers to the model schema and in a `methods` method the `this` refers to the document instance.

For example, you might use a `statics` method to run a query like:

```
catSchema.statics.findGingerCats = function() {
  return this.find({colour: 'ginger'}) // this = catSchema
}

const Cat = model('cat', catSchema)
const gingerCats = Cat.findGingerCats()
```

This will give you back a list of documents. You can use a `methods` method to augment the document like so:

```
catSchema.methods.getAge = function() {
  return Date.now() - this.date_of_birth // this = document instance
}

const gingerCats = Cat.findGingerCats()
const age_of_first_ginger_cat = gingerCats[0].getAge()
```

There are a few more examples in the official documentation:

- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods
- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics